# How to return a response every second in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have this simple controller that returns data:

```
namespace ns
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ServerSentEventController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task Get()
        {
            var response = Response;

            for (var i = 0; true; i++)
            {
                // Thread.Sleep(1000); // <-- (*) Blocks
                await response.WriteAsync($"data: Controller {i} at {DateTime.Now}\r\r");
                response.Body.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Commenting out `(*)`, responses are flushed "at CPU speed":
[image]

I'd like a response every second. When I include `(*)`, then however nothing is printed on the browser, I guess the server is waiting for the response to be complete, which obviously it never is.

Comment: Forget `Thread.Sleep`. Use `await Task.Delay`.

Comment: Consider using SignalR framework. It will allow you to send messages from the server to the client using WebSocket.

Comment: Either use SignalR or make sure teh client (browser) pulls the data each 1 second.

Comment: Webapi is "one request leads to *one* response" and you want to have lots of responses

Answer (score 0):

Use ***System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne()*** instead ***Thread.Sleep()***

```
namespace ns
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class ServerSentEventController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Get()
    {
        var response = Response;

        for (var i = 0; true; i++)
        {
             new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(1000);
            await response.WriteAsync($"data: Controller {i} at {DateTime.Now}\r\r");
            response.Body.Flush();
        }
    }
}
}
```

or use ***await Task.Delay***

```
namespace ns
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class ServerSentEventController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Get()
    {
        var response = Response;

        for (var i = 0; true; i++)
        {
             await Task.Delay(1000);
            await response.WriteAsync($"data: Controller {i} at {DateTime.Now}\r\r");
            response.Body.Flush();
        }
    }
}
}
```

It is better to use a timer and use SignaR for send data from server to client